# How to make query to filter data from database table in Django?

Tags: django

There are three tables which are:
models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    gen_choices = (
        ("Male", "Male"),
        ("Female", "Female"),
        ("Third", "Third"),
        )
    enrollNo = models.IntegerField(default=add_one)
    fname = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=26)
    lname = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=26)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gen_choices)
    dob= models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    userID = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="stdimages/", null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Entexaminfo(models.Model):
    entexamses = (
        ("June Session", "June Session"),
        ("December Session", "December Session"),
        )
    approve_choice = (
        ("Pending", "Pending"),
        ("Accepted", "Accepted"),
        ("Rejected", "Rejected"),
        )
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=entexamses)
    enrollno = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #programs = models.ManyToManyField(Programs, related_name='proNames', default=0)
    program = models.ManyToManyField(Programs, default=0)
    center = models.ForeignKey(Excenter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remarks = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=256, default="-")
    #status = models.BooleanField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=approve_choice, default="Pending")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager
    # for admin pannel to display for correction
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ename

class Ex_schedule(models.Model):
    exDate = models.DateField()
    exTime = models.TimeField()
    exDuration = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=26)
    programs = models.OneToOneField(Programs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exRemarks = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    exStatus = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager
    # for admin pannel to display for correction
    def __str__(self):
        return self.exDate

class Programs(models.Model):
    proName = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=26)
    proDuration =models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=26)
    proFees = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    proDetails = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=26, null=True)
    proStatus = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager
    # for admin pannel to display for correction
    def __str__(self):
        return self.proName
```

I want to filter data from three tables (i.e. Student, Entexaminfo & Ex_schedule) giving a enrollno of student table, But I am not being able to filter data from Ex_schedule table because a student can choose more than one subject, according to chosen subjects data should be filter from Ex_schedule table. For this I have tried following codes but program id i have given manually, I want to replace it.
views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/user/login')
def hall_ticket(request):
    query = request.GET['enrollno']
    if query:
        entedetail = Student.objects.filter(enrollNo=query)
        for obj in entedetail:
            global id #To avoid 'local variable 'id' referenced before assignment' error message
            id = obj.id
        ent1 = Entexaminfo.objects.filter(enrollno=id)
        
        esch = Ex_schedule.objects.filter(programs=1)
        params = {'entedetails': entedetail, 'ent1': ent1, 'query': query, 'esch': esch, 'title': 'Entrance Exam Hall Ticket'}
    else:
        params = {'error': 'Please Enter Your Enrollment No.', 'title': 'Entrance Exam Hall Ticket'}
    return render(request, 'hall_ticket.html', params)
```

Please guide me for it.